# Select takes a long time in a 160GB database

Tags: performance, sqlite

I have an SQLite database of 160GB. There is an index on the `id` column and `stage` column of table `hwmp`.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_hwmp_id ON hwmp (id, stage);
```

When I do a count of rows the query returns in 0.09 seconds.

```
sqlite> select count (*) from hwmp where id = 2000 and stage = 4;
59397
Run Time: real 0.091 user 0.000074 sys 0.080494
```

However, for a select all the real time is 85 seconds. The user and system time combined is only 2.5 seconds. Why would the real time be so high?

```
select * from hwmp where id = 2000 and stage = 4;
Run Time: real 85.420 user 0.801639 sys 1.754250
```

How to fix it? Another query on a sqlite3 database (300MB) used to return in 20ms. Today, it was taking 652ms.

```
Run Time: real 0.652 user 0.018766 sys 0.010595
```

There is something wrong with the Linux environment today. I downloaded the same SQLite to my Mac and it ran quickly.

```
Run Time: real 0.028 user 0.005990 sys 0.010420
```

It is using the index:

```
sqlite> explain query plan select * from hwmp where id = 78 and stage = 4;
QUERY PLAN
`--SEARCH hwmp USING INDEX idx_hwmp_id (id=? AND stage=?)
Run Time: real 0.005 user 0.000857 sys 0.000451
```

Comment: The count is fast because it only has to consult the index. Selecting all the columns of each row requires looking up each matching row in the table after finding it in the index; a lot more work. See https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html for an introduction to how it works.

Comment: Depending on what you're using to run the query, *displaying* the results can take a big chunk of time when you have that many, too.

Comment: @Shawn It should not take 85s to read 60,000 records. I updated my question with some more context.

Comment: There's a lot of factors; you haven't mentioned how you're benchmarking, if it's consistent or only slow on a newly opened database (Which is to be expected the way sqlite works)... things like disk access times, caching (Both OS level and internal to sqlite), using different versions of sqlite, etc. can all be issues. Shoot, if it's even using the index (Try `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT * FROM ...` to confirm it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant setting is `pragma cache_size = 200000;` 200000 pages of 4096 bytes. After setting that, for the first time query, it takes approximately 3s and second time query takes 0.28s. Phew.

The cache settings improved the performance for some time. We are working off an AWS linux VM with EBS SSD attached. There seems to be problem in the environment as well. The query times in my Mac is 6.3 times faster than the AWS linux / EBS environment.